# How do I disable the local screen in Vino VNC?

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, vnc, remote, vino

As the title says, when I remote into my machine through VNC, how do I disable the local screen? I am currently running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04

Comment: vino-server is really intended as a desktop *sharing* service: if you want an *independent* desktop session, the usual way to do that would be to run a traditional vncserver (e.g. tightvncserver or vnc4server)